# Marshalling from System::String^ to char* in c++

Tags: c++, c++-cli

There are mentioned conversions between System::String and const char* in [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb384865.aspx) article.

My question is: Is it possible to make conversion from System::String to char*(note on missing const) with this construction(marshal_context)?

And if not what is recommended solution of this problem?

Am I forced to use older Marshal::StringToHGlobalAnsi?

There is also additional question in comments.

Comment: Turn it into an `std::string` and then do `&str[0]` to get the underlying `char*`?

Comment: @RichardJ.RossIII `c_str()` returns `const char*`.

Comment: Nice idea! But maybe there is some nicer solution where I don't have to take care of memory leaks etc.

Comment: What memory leaks? Anyway if you don't want to do it that way you're probably stuck with `StringToHGlobalAnsi`.

Comment: @Rapptz OK Your solution is very nice and simple. One thing remaiming when I use marshal_context(created with gcnew) .. then your hacks:) .. then &str[0] is sent to function(from external library)(and there memory is probably modified) will the "delete context;"(context is instance of marshal_context) delete all memory without problem ? or what does "delete context;" do ?

Comment: This is the reason why people should learn C first heh..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can obtain the underlying c-style string by using `c_str()`, a method provided by Strings. It's `const`, but you can just copy it away into your own, variable `char*`.

Just allocate a buffer big enough, like you would with `malloc`, and then `strncpy` into it. There's a hundred different ways of doing this, but it all boils down to reserve memory, copy the string, have fun with it.

Comment: Very nice. This way I know what is deleted and what is not. I wrote my question pretty unclear but you got it. Nice determining. Thanks